# what to do when python tkinter with multiprossesing opens 4 new gui's

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

i trying to make a safefail button ("q") if my code breaks everything etc.
so when i hit "q" on my keyboard all my displays are gonna enable in case everthing goes dark. i got it to work but it was slow so am trying with multiprossesing but when i hit q the code starts the gui 4 more times, but it works, so all screen turn on again.

so how do i stop it from making more gui windows?

````
import tkinter as tk
# import keyboard
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def setupWork():
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 4")
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 3 ")
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 2 ")
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 1 ")

def setupMovie():
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 4")
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 3")
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 2")
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 1")

def onlyMain():
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 3")
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 4")
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 2")
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /disable 1")

# def enableAll():
#     os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 4")
#     print("1")
#     time.sleep(1)
#     os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 3")
#     print("2")
#     time.sleep(1)
#     os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 2")
#     print("3")
#     time.sleep(1)
#     os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 1")
#     print("4")
#     time.sleep(1)

# def testkey(event):
#     enableAll()



def D1():
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 4")
    print("1")
def D2():
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 3")
    print("2")
def D3():
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 2")
    print("3")
def D4():
    os.system("C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 1")
    print("4")    


root = tk.Tk()

# fail safe if rip
# root.bind("q", testkey)
root.bind("q", D1)
root.bind("q", D2)
root.bind("q", D3)
root.bind("q", D4)




background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file= "C:/Users/ERD/Documents/codes/MultiMonitorScrips/background.png")
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# background_logo = tk.PhotoImage(file=)q

root.title('MMTS')
root.minsize(width=250, height=100)


button_A = tk.Button(root, text='Work', command=setupWork, bg='gray80')
button_A.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3 ,relheight=0.35, relwidth=0.35)

button_B = tk.Button(root, text='Movie', command=setupMovie, bg='gray80')
button_B.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.3 ,relheight=0.35, relwidth=0.35)

Button_C = tk.Button(root, text='Main', command=onlyMain, bg='gray80')
Button_C.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.88, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.3)

root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d1 = Process(target=D1)
    d2 = Process(target=D2)
    d3 = Process(target=D3)
    d4 = Process(target=D4)
    d1.start()
    d2.start()
    d3.start()
    d4.start()
    d1.join()
    d2.join()
    d3.join()
    d4.join()```
````

Comment: okey, so i think i know the awnser but not how code it. i need the d1,start() etc... to wait for the keypress "q"

Answer (score 1):

Based on the paths in your functions, you are running on windows.

What you are seeing is a side-effect of the way `multiprocessing` has to work on ms-windows. On ms-windows, multiprocessing has to `import` your file in all worker processes. That import should run without side effects such as creating windows.

So you should move everything *except* the function definitions to the `if __name__ is "__main__"` block. Especially creating the window and running the mainloop.

**Edit:**

Additionally, I'm not sure why you are even using `multiprocessing` here? I assume that `MultiMonitorTool.exe` finishes quickly.

After the `mainloop`, just call

```
for n in range(4, 0, -1):
    os.system(
      "C:\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable " + str(n)
    )
```

That should switch all monitors back on.

Comment: hi, i kinda understand what you mean, but could you make the code so i understand 100% ? :)

Comment: Move `if __name__ is "__main__"` to just before `root = tk.Tk()`, and correct the indentation.

Comment: i made it so i it prints what display who as been diabaled or enabled, and it looks like it runs the multiprosses first and not when its beeing called

Comment: I don't think this is unique to windows. On all platforms, the module must be imported into the new processes.

Comment: @BryanOakley UNIX-like operating systems just use `fork`, generally, which doesn't need to do that. The `spawn` method used on ms-windows exists because that OS doesn't have `fork`. So "safe importing of main module" is a restriction particular to the "spawn" and "forkserver" methods of starting new processes, according to the multiprocessing documentation. And I cannot determine quickly which OS uses forkserver by default, if any.